# ggplot add a legend to manual curves

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

```
x  <- seq(0, 50, 1) 
y1 <- exp(0.0509*x)
y2 <- exp(0.0519*x)
df <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +                    
  geom_line(aes(y=y1), colour="blue") +  
  geom_line(aes(y=y2), colour="red")
```

According to the code, I would like how to add a legend called "group 1" for y1 and "group 2" for y2.
I've tried many things that I've seen on this forum, but I always get an error.

Comment: well, what kind of error?

Comment: well for instance i did  geom_line(aes(y=y2), colour="red", labels="test") and I try so many things that I canot mention all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
gg <- melt(df,id="x")
ggplot(gg, aes(x=x, y=value, color=variable))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]